# What is a Triple Spindle Boring machine used for?

Tags: tools

Obviously (?) its used for boring three holes at a time, or maybe slots if the drill mounting block is designed for sideways forces (i.e., not a tapered fitting without a drawbar). But why is this particular configuration so useful as to have a large stationary machine dedicated to it? What type of joinery or other fabrication makes use of this?

From the example photos below, you can see the 3 boring spindles are relatively close together and possibly all at the same height. Although it looks like the outer two may have adjustable positions.

(I think the triple-spindle portion may be a removable head, in which case this machine might serve other operations as well. I can more easily imagine what a single-spindle boring machine would be used for. But > 1 not as much.)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is quite literally for boring three holes at once, not just for speed (although that's certainly part of it) but for absolute repeatability — the holes will never be spaced anything other than perfectly. This is for production woodworking in a commercial environment in case that's not obvious, where time is money and literally shaving off a couple of minutes each time could be very beneficial. *"What type of joinery... makes use of this?"* I presume there's no other use for this other than for dowel joints, used in place of M&Ts.

Comment: @jdv the question alludes to that. Would be interesting to learn what other types of heads are often used.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs answering that would take some research knowing the brand of machine and tool. Though, it appears to be made by Woodtech Machinery, LLC. So, any further specific research would included spelunking based on that.